# Rails on Docker から api を叩いた際の Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, google-api

### やりたいこと

- Rails の Book モデルから google books api を叩いて書籍情報のレスポンスを取得したい

### 発生したエラー

```
web_1        | Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL (Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Address not available - connect(2) for nil port 80)):
web_1        |   
web_1        | app/models/book.rb:24:in `search'
web_1        | app/controllers/books_controller.rb:3:in `search'
```

### コード

フォームから送られてきたキーワード（書籍名や著者など）を使って API を叩きます。

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @results = Book.search(params[:book_search][:search_key_word])
  end
end
```

日本語が含まれるので、 `url_encode` メソッドでエンコードしています。

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  class << self
    def search(key_word)
      api_endpoint = ERB::Util.url_encode("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{key_word}&maxResults=20")
      response = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(api_endpoint)) # ここで上記のエラーが発生しています。
      JSON.parse(response)
    end
  end
end
```

同じエンドポイントに対して curl を実行すると当然適切にレスポンスが返ります。

dockerを使っていることが何か関係しているのでしょうか？
alpine linux をベースにしています。
https://hub.docker.com/layers/ruby/library/ruby/2.6.6-alpine/images/sha256-95d5b6bf7084a6a0f04b48a7fc1c533ccb15e1550c670ff589ef56e620f40286?context=explore

### 環境

- docker 2.3.0.4
- docker-compose 3.8
- railsコンテナbaseイメージ ruby:2.6.6-alpine
- ruby 2.6.6
- rails 6.0.3.2

---

何か分かることがあればご教授頂けますと幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

`ERB::Util.url_encode` が不要なのではないかと思います。

```
api_endpoint = ERB::Util.url_encode("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{key_word}&maxResults=20")
```

ここを

```
api_endpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{key_word}&maxResults=20"
```

このように変更してみてはいかがでしょうか。

---

[追記]

`key_word` が外部から与えられるような信頼できない値の場合は、URL 全体をエンコード(エスケープ)するのではなく、`key_word` だけをエンコードしてそれを URL の一部として使用したほう安全です。
その場合は `URI.encode_www_form_component` が使用できます。

例:

```
encoded = URI.encode_www_form_component(key_word)
uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{encoded}&maxResults=20"
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！そのようにすると、URI.parse した時に `URI must be ascii only` になってしまいます。。。解決したので原因を載せておきますね。

Answer (score 0):

解決しました。

原因としては、

```
ERB::Util.url_encode("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{key_word}&maxResults=20")
```

この部分でエンコードした時に返ってくる文字列をそのまま `URI.parse` に渡すと、`URI::Generic` が返っていました。uriのhostもscheme もnil になっていて正しく取得できていなかったようです。
それをそのまま Net::HTTP.get に渡しているので表題のようなエラーとなっていました。

`URI.encode` が非推奨のため、他のメソッドでエンコードしたかったです。
最終的には、`WEBrick::HTTPUtils.#escape` を使ってエンコードした文字列を URI.parse すると URI::HTTP のインスタンスが返り、scheme なども正しくセットされた状態となり解決しました。

ありがとうございました。

- 参考

```
def search(key_word)
uri = URI.parse(WEBrick::HTTPUtils.escape("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{key_word}&maxResults=20"))
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```

Comment: 私の回答に追記しました。